# Android : OpenGL, Textview

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have read about accessing xml layout component thorugh opengl renderer and I`m still can`t do it.. can anyone tell me how to do it?

My xml layout is using relativelayout..

this is a part of my java class for set the renderer

GamePlayActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGLSurfaceView = new GameView(this);
    mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GameRenderer(this,GamePlayActivity.this));
    setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
    sv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameviewxml1);
    sv.addView(mGLSurfaceView, 0);
```

and this is my renderer constructor

GameRenderer.java

```
private GamePlayActivity gpa;
public GameRenderer(Context context,GamePlayActivity gp)
{
    grContext = context;
    gpa = gp;
}
```

I have a textview I want to change the text when renderer finish doing some animation.. I tried using this in renderer class

```
gpa.roll.setText("Done");
```

but the app crash after that.. I wonder where I was wrong?If I missimg some data that I need to show just tell me.. I`ll post it..

Comment: anyone can help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you pass in GPA, but that's okay. If you declare the SurfaceView in xml, it should be pretty easy to position everything that way. For example:

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ad_detect" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_temp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ad_detect"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_value_temp_bkrd"
    android:shadowColor="#00FF00"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="10"
    android:text="@string/temp"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry. If you still can't get it the tut labeled Building a Custom Camera App should get you on your way. It shows you how to make a callback and you can overlay widgets easily then. Maybe this won't work for you. I dunno. Good luck. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: so I need to change the relative layout to surfaceview?